# Why is this makefile restarting/reparsing many times?

Tags: makefile

I wanted to keep a log of previously compiled code so I can be consistent when setting the compiling options. I devised the following scheme but it has a weird behavior that I don't quite fully understand. Here is a simplified version that reproduces the error:

Makefile:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL = final

MKFILES = Makefile Makefile.checks
include Makefile.checks

.PHONY: final
final: info.txt results.txt
    @cat $^

results.txt: $(MKFILES) | .PRELIM
    @echo 'First file with opt=$(opt)' > $@

info.txt: info.src $(MKFILES) | .PRELIM
    @cat $< > $@
    @echo 'Internal record of opt=$(opt)' >> $@

.PHONY: .FORCE
.FORCE:

.PHONY: .PRELIM
.PRELIM: Makefile.log

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf *.txt *.log
```

Makefile.checks:

```
# SETUPS & CHECKS

opt ?= 0
BUILDSTAT := 0

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ("$(wildcard Makefile.log)","")

    include Makefile.log
    ifneq ($(opt),$(oldopt))
        $(warning Previously compiled opt = $(oldopt))
        $(warning Currently requested opt = $(opt))
        BUILDSTAT := 1
    endif

endif
endif

# RESOLUTION SECTION
ifneq ($(BUILDSTAT),0)

info.txt: .FORCE
Makefile.log: .FORCE

    $(warning The build is not consistent, a clean make is recomended. )
    ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),anyway)
        $(warning To force compilation, run 'make anyway opt=X' )
        $(error Aborting compilation)
    endif

endif

.PHONY: anyway
anyway: $(.DEFAULT_GOAL)

Makefile.log:
    @echo 'Creating new Makefile.log'
    @echo '########################################' > Makefile.log
    @echo 'oldopt    := $(opt)' >> Makefile.log
    @echo 'BUILDSTAT := $(BUILDSTAT)' >> Makefile.log
    @echo '########################################' >> Makefile.log
```

The Makefiles create the log and check for the previous options: `make` followed by `make opt=1` behaves as expected by issuing the warning and stopping. However, when I `make anyway opt=1` the makefile seems to parse the `Makefile.checks` many times before actually compiling:

```
Makefile.checks:12: Previously compiled opt = 0
Makefile.checks:13: Currently requested opt = 1
Makefile.checks:26: The build is not consistent, a clean make is recomended. 
Creating new Makefile.log
Makefile.checks:26: The build is not consistent, a clean make is recomended. 
Creating new Makefile.log
(...repeated many times...)
Makefile.checks:26: The build is not consistent, a clean make is recomended. 
Creating new Makefile.log
This is a personal log
Internal record of opt=1
First file with opt=0
```

I **suspect** this may have something to do with how Makefile re-parses itself after modifying the Makefile.log that is itself included in one of the MKFILES that causes the whole list of targets to recompile. I tried using the `-d` option but it is not helping me much. This design ended up being quite convoluted but I didn't know how to simplify it, and I don't know enough about how makefile works to decipher what is happening on my own either.

I would be really thankful for an explanation of this error. Which dependency is causing the cycle and why it eventually leaves it and moves on to finish compilation? Do you think there is a better way to record compilation options?

---

EDIT: I will be adding here further requested information/explanations. I modified a bit the code to simplify it.

What I'm trying to do is to store the compilation options used in the last build so as not to be mixing options when recompiling only part of a code (or at least to be warned that this is what I'm doing). The way I implemented this is in the `Makefile.checks`: options are written into / loaded from a `Makefile.log` and `BUILDSTAT` is a kind of boolean to check if there were discrepancies or not and keep track of it in the successive builds.

`Makefile.checks` first sets defaults, then checks if the log exist and loads the "old" options in separated variables and then compares the two to check for discrepancies. If any is found, it issues a warning here and then later checks again and stops (this separation makes more sense when you have more than one option) unless explicitly asked to ignore them by using the target `anyway`. In this last case, both the log and the file info.txt (which is another way to store the options) need to be updated with the last build info (and specially the `BUILDSTAT=1` to keep record that the build may have a "mixed compilation").

---

EDIT - "SOLUTION": Apparently if instead of "forcing" the recompilation of the log, I make the log itself a phony target (inside the if), it prevents this behavior. I still have found no drawbacks to this approach, but it does feel a bit "dirty".

Comment: Well, you've use `FORCE` as a prerequisite for `Makefile.log`, which means it's always out of date, which means that the file is always be rebuilt, which means that make will always re-exec itself trying to read the newest version.  If you explained more clearly what you want to accomplish we can better provide help.

Comment: Ok, sure, I just added a bit of an explanation. I also changed the dependency of the log on FORCE so that it will only has it if different options are requested, but it still has the same behavior. I cannot remove it definitively because I need to keep track of the inconsistencies.